# Firebase Notifications not working

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've uploaded the p12 file to Firebase, enables push notifications in app capabilities and in the App ID. I also did test it on a device not the simulator. Also the analytics aren't working but the database is. Here's my Appdelegate.swift

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase
import UserNotifications
import FirebaseAnalytics
import FirebaseMessaging


@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?




    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        FIRApp.configure()

        FIRDatabase.database().persistenceEnabled = true


        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
                options: authOptions,
                completionHandler: {_, _ in })

        } else {
            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
                UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }


        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

        return true
    }
```

Xcode 8.2, Swift 3

Comment: Hi. Can you provide more details as to why Firebase Notifications doesn't work?  It's hard to tell what's wrong in your post.

Comment: About an hour later the notification is come through. But now when I try send a notification it doesn't come at all @al